# How to connect AWS AppSync to MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aws-appsync

AppSync is good that it is a managed GraphQL service.

But I dont want to use the DynamoDB, can I plug to MongoDB?

How to do it?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot directly connect MongoDB to AppSync, But you can create and attach a Lambda function as the DataSource and put all your configuration & mapper logic there. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-lambda-resolvers.html) is a small tutorial about how to use Lambda resolvers. For your case, you would have to extend it and add MongoDB specific configuration & logic.

Answer (score 1):

Update: AWS AppSync can be connected directly to MongoDB Atlas using their data API and AppSync's HTTP resolver.

This is outlined in details (repo included) in this AWS blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/the-fullstack-guide-to-using-aws-appsync-and-mongodb-atlas/